# Sql query to find Album records which have no Song in the Songs table

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am using a sqlite database in C# and need help with a  a sql query, I do not know if what I am trying to get is possible in single query my current solution is very inefficient and poor which I have put it in the end but first my problem...

I have two tables Songs and Albums, the tables are shown below

I need to write a query to get all Album records which have no song in the songs table...

```
    Songs

    Artist           Album         Filename        
    Taylor Swift     Red           track1.mp3      
    Taylor Swift     Red           track2.mp3      
    Taylor Swift     Fearless      track1.mp3      
    Taylor Swift     Fearless      track2.mp3    
    Shakira          GrandesExitos track1.mp3


    Albums

    Artist           Album 
    Taylor Swift     Red    
    Taylor Swift     Fearless  
    Taylor Swift     Beautiful Eyes  
    Shakira          The remixes
    Jackson          Fearless
    Taylor Swift     The remixes
```

Need all records of Albums which have no Song in the Songs table,.

```
    So in this case the records of Album I need are

    Taylor Swift     Beautiful Eyes  
    Shakira          The remixes
    Jackson          Fearless
    Taylor Swift     The remixes
```

My current solution is very inefficient and present below , I only need help with query not the C# code..

```
    dt = db.GetDataTable(String.Format("select distinct artist, album from files");

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
       string artist = (string)r[0];
       string album = (string)r[1];
       //I have create a status column in the Albums table to solve this problem
       query = string.Format("update Albums set status = {0} where artist = '{1}' and album = '{2}'", 1, artist, album);

       int nModified = db.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
     }
     // Then I get all records from Albums whose status is not 1
      dt = db.GetDataTable(select * from Albums where status = 0");

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL statement `EXISTS` to check if no songs exist for specific album:

```
SELECT alb.Artist, alb.Album
FROM Albums alb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Songs s 
    WHERE s.Artist = alb.Artist AND s.Album = alb.Album
)
```

This SQL Statement returns all records from table `Album`, that have no related records in table `Songs`.

Comment: SELECT 1 ? did you mean SELECT * in the sub query

Comment: @Ahmed No, I meant `1`. It doesn't matter if you select `*`, `1` or anything else, the main point is that if subquery returns any records (it doesn't matter what the columns are) then `EXISTS` returns true, otherwise - false. So I chose to select constant value `1` instead of selecting all the columns. It is very likely most SQL engines optimize the query the same way, I just chose to use `1` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Select * from albums where album not in(select album from songs)
```

Comment: This is not correct, Album does not uniquely identify rows in either of the tables, The final result may have an Album record from a different artist.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT artist,album FROM Albums WHERE album NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT Album FROM songs)
```

Comment: This is not correct, Album does not uniquely identify rows in either of the tables, The final result may have an Album record from a different artist.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget about joins.

```
select
    album.Artist, album.Album
from
    Albums album
    left outer join Songs song
        on album.Artist = song.Artist and album.Album = song.Album
where
    song.Filename is null -- if it's valid for some reason to have a null song name, just change this to song.Artist is null
```

This way you don't need nested queries.

Comment: If you are going to down vote a solution, have the decency to give an explanation.